# Manually way to trigger the CustomRowFilterEvent

Tags: c#, devexpress

We want to filter some rows in XtraGrid with Winforms.
RefreshData() can take a long time (all rows seem to be read agin from DB).

The method to fire teh event seems to be hidden in the depth of DevExpress,

```
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.RaiseCustomRowFilter(Int32 listSourceRow)
```

(a protected internal method)

Is there some way to fire the event, if only the Gridview is known?

My problems begins at the first stage. How do i get the method?

> MethodInfo methodInfo = gridView.GetType().GetMethod("RaiseCustomRowFilter");
>   returns null

Comment: Why don't you just use a dataview and filter it?

Comment: @Stig I think the DataView works on the cutomers Filter. We want to also add an invisible Filter which is only there to "soft delete" items. DataView coudl also be an additional level of abstraction, is it needed fro this usecase?

Comment: DataView is a virtual DataTable on top of a regular DataTable.
usefull for filtering the datasource on the client.
If you don't use DataTables to hold your data, there are other ways of filtering the source. You can always use a DataSource to filter your data.

Comment: Few problems with this approach: We are talking about a "grown" product. If something is changeing the datasource, the odds are quite good to get a nice red cross (even with gridview.BeginDataEdit()...EndDataEdit). It can also be the case that this takes a long time. An additional Bindingsource would also be an additional level of abbstraction. Funily we have a third party ORM where our datasource is inherited from bindingsource. Except it doese not support filtering... Also changes to this  are not visible in DataGridView, except DGV is doing a complete refresh.

Comment: Sad to hear that, but if your datasource support IBindingListView, it already have a filter option. Never had any performance issues with filtering this way (with sensible amounts of data)

Comment: 'ObjectView : BindingSource, IModifiable and BindingSource : Component, IBindingListView, IBindingList, ...' so I don't know why 'Filter' is not supported for ObjectView. DevExpress told that the ObjectView calls the DB for every object they ask during RefreshData. Therfore I would like to avoid refreshdata. The people of the ORM also say they have no issue with normal Grids... That is why i search for a way to call only the CustomRowFilter for a single row.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Linq included:

```
DataView dv = TheDataTable.AsDataView();
dv.RowFilter = "mycolumn > 3";
gridControl1.DataSource = dv;
```

You can do this with almost any datasource

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource;
bs.DataSource = theDataSorce;
bs.Filter = "mycolumn > 3";
gridControl1.DataSource = bs;
```

these filters are not visible for the users.